# Azure: Rails and PostgreSQL on the same VM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, azure, virtual-machine

I'm trying to combine a Rails app and PostgreSQL on the same Azure virtual machine.
I installed PostgreSQL 9.5 following [this guide](http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/setting-up-postgresql-in-azure-vm/) and it seems to give no problems by itself. Now the problem is, I cannot install the `pg` gem. Specifically, running the command `gem install pg -v '0.19.0'`, it gives me the following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.19.0/ext
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20170122-18144-1ee3id1.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side     extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may 
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.3
        --with-pg
        --without-pg
        --enable-windows-cross
        --disable-windows-cross
        --with-pg-config
        --without-pg-config
        --with-pg_config
        --without-pg_config
        --with-pg-dir
        --without-pg-dir
        --with-pg-include
        --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
        --with-pg-lib
        --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which      can be found here:

  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/pg-0.19.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.19.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/pg-0.19.0/gem_make.out
```

Any help is really appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as it was, I just needed to install postgresql-server-dev-9.5 on my Azure Ubuntu VM. I just overlooked the error log :D

Answer (score 0):

What is the response of `which pg_config`

If it is something like:

/usr/bin/which: no pg_config in...

Try installing again with below command:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-devel
```

Comment: `/usr/bin/pg_config`